# I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but come alive with the wind. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but come alive with the wind. What am I?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-answer-to-this-riddle-I-speak-without-a-mouth-and-hear-without-ears-I-have-no-body-but-come-alive-with-the-wind-What-am-I https://www.buzzfeed.com/avaerickson04/how-many-of-these-riddles-can-you-solve-fn4aj6evg9 https://facebook.com/SBCEssendon/posts/riddle-of-the-daycan-you-or-your-family-solve-this-onei-speak-without-a-mouth-an/2576047322609775/

Comment: @msh210 stop cheating and revealing the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> An echo?

I speak without a mouth

> An echo echoes without a mouth.

and hear without ears.

> An echo listens to you and copies you, so it listens without ears.

I have no body, but come alive with the wind.

> The wind of our breath allows us to hear the echo.